# Can't execute SQL Server stored procedure in Access module

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

In Access I created a form with Text1, List1, and Command1 elements.
The code for command button is:

```
    Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    con.Open "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=192.168.100.41,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;"
    cmd.ActiveConnection = con
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@keyword", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, Trim(Text1.Value))
    cmd.CommandText = "stored_procedure"
    Set rs = cmd.Execute(, , adCmdStoredProc)
    If (rs.RecordCount <> 0) Then
    Do While Not rs.EOF
    Me.List1.AddItem (rs.Fields(0).Value & " | " & rs.Fields(1).Value & " | " & rs.Fields(2).Value)
    rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    End If
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing
    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing
    End Sub
```

When I try to run the code, nothing happens. No error. Seems like button is empty.
The SP works fine in SQL server.
The same button code, works fine in Excel form.
If I replace SP part with [rs.open "select * from table where keyword like.."] works fine
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use a client side cursor, I would debug.print rs.RecordCount to check what it thinks are the returned records.

```
conn.cursorlocation=aduseclient
```

Comment: debug.print rs.RecordCount >>>> immediate window is blank. but, actually sp returns records. conn.cursorlocation=aduseclient >>> no effect

Comment: The SP might return records , but your debug would indicate access doesn't think so, so you code won't run. You shouldn't need to with a ADODB recordset but try a rs.movelast rs.movefirst to get it load the entire recordset. Also try `rs.Cursortype = aduseclient`